# disable field from editing but not from creating view sonata bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata, disable

I have an application using Sonata Admin for the back-office.

If I use `disabled => true` it will remove the field from being editable in edit and create view.

Is there a way to disable it only on the edit screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the following code to get the subject of the Admin and check if subject exist then disable the field. Update your `configureFormFields` method inside admin.

```
/** @var YourClass $subject */
$subject = $this->getSubject();
    
if($subject) {
   // DISABLE THE FIELD
} else {
   // ENABLE THE FIELD
}
```

Comment: The subject seems to be set in edit and also in the create mode so it doesn't help me.

Comment: But it's working with `$this->isCurrentRoute('create')`.